# Asking for help in post request with RestKit

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, restkit

I have to access Rest api in iOS and i am using RestKit for that. The server only accept POST request and send response in JSON. Just help me to call the login api using RestKit. The url is like:

http://mobile.domian.co/apiversion/user/login

and Post parametersare:

app_key(string),signature(string),timestamp(dateTime),user_id(string),password(string).

available response representations

```
{
"status": "0",
"result": {
    "error_code": "1",
    "error_msg": "Login failed. Wrong username or password"
}
```

> {
>       "status": "1",
>       "result": {
>           "data": {
>               "avatar": "",
>               "email": "sd.p@clozette.co",
>               "user_name": "sd",
>               "newsletter": "1",
>               "bio_data": "About myself",
>               "mth_dob": "1",
>               "yr_dob": "1981",
>               "hometown": "",
>               "dob_priv": "1",
>               "hometown_priv": "1",
>               "bio_data_priv": "1",
>   “block_comment_notification”:”0”,
>   “block_liked_notification”:”0”,
>   }

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the Answer(you should convert your datetime to string) :-

```
        NSString *post =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"app_key=%@&signature=%@&timestamp=%@&user_id=%@&password=%@",appKEY,Signature,Datetime,UID,Password];

    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"Your URL"]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

    NSError *error;
    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSData *returnData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
    if (error)
{
    NSLog(@"Error is %@",[error localizedDescription]);
}

    returnString=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    if(!returnString)
    {
        UIAlertView *erroralert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"There is an error getting response" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
        [erroralert show];
        [erroralert release];
    }
    else 
    {
        NSLog(@"%@",returnString);
    }
    SBJSON *json = [[SBJSON new] autorelease];
    NSMutableDictionary *dic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[json objectWithString:returnString error:nil]];
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I used that code but not working.
Should i call the delegate method there?

Comment: How it's not working means you are not getting response? plz check parameters spell by spell. Paremeters must match with the web service that you are calling at your URL.

Comment: hey dh14-sl, i dont know whats wrong going on there. if i am doing anything wrong at least some message will come from the server. NSData is 0 byte here.

Comment: it works anyway...mistake in creating header string. there was "&" between them where i was using ",". thanks...answer accepted :)

Comment: Sorry for that mistake,Actually, Thanks to you for correcting my answer!I edited as you suggested.